# Как добавить N элементов со ссылками?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть N. Необходимо при помощи jQuery добавить N ссылок `<a href=""></a>` с id от 1 до N

Т.е., если `N = 3` - добавить 3 ссылки:

```
<a href="/page1"></a>
<a href="/page2"></a>
<a href="/page3"></a>
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Что пробовали? Что не получилось?

Comment: Я пытался найти в принципе как можно с множителями работать на jquery, но либо я не правильно запросы делаю, либо я чего то не понимаю)

Comment: Причем тут множители вообще? Почему нельзя просто в цикле добавить N ссылок?

Comment: Хорошо, как добавить N ссылок, чтобы каждый href содержал page+1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать массив из `N` пустых элементов. Каждый элемент заменить на HTML с подставленным нужным значением числа от 1 до N. Склеить элементы массива в одну строку через некий разделитель. Вставить весь HTML в нужном месте документа:

```js
var N = 3;

var tmpl = '<a href="/page%ID%">страница %ID%</a>'; // темплейт
// вместо %ID% подставим 1...3

var html = (Array.apply(null, Array(N))) // массив из N пустых элем.
  .map((e,i)=>{return tmpl.replace( /%ID%/g, i+1)}) // заменить каждый
     // на tmpl с подставленным нужным значением ID
     // i считается от 0 до N-1, поэтому заменяем на i+1

  .join( "<br>\n") // объединить в одну строку через разделитель
;
$( '#out').html( html); // вставить готовый HTML в нужном месте
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: ну есть же уже [шаблоны строк](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) зачем _replace_? :-)

Comment: @Grundy круто, не знал. Можно прям надёжно использовать в боевых проектах?

Comment: Нет конечно :-) если не ошибаюсь IE его не особо поддерживает, хотя если его выбросить то вполне можно

Answer (score 7):

Давайте начнем с того, что библиотека JQuery используется в первую очередь для работы с DOM деревом страницы. Поэтому для работы с тем, что этого не касается, она практически не используется.

Что бы решить задачу, надо знать чистый JS, а не JQuery. Можно использовать простой цикл или как вариант более сложные методы:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(function (_, i) {return i;}).map(function(item){
  return "<a href=\"/page"+(item+1)+"\"></a>";
})
```

Comment: @Sergiks, а разве у меня не так?

Comment: а, да, всё в порядке.

Comment: А если `Array.from(Array(5).keys());`?

Answer (score 5):

```
function generateLinks(n){
    var str = '';
    for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        str = str + '<a href="/page'+i+'">'+i+'</a>';
    }
    $('#block').append(str);  // это если добавить в конец какого-то блока
    $('#block').html(str);    // это если заменить содержимов блока
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Довольно просто, хотя прежде чем прогать неплохо бы мануальчик открыть

```
var n = 'тут количество ссылок'; 
for(var i=1; i<n; i++){
  var newLink = "<a href='page"+i+"'>Ковычка малех не там стояла</a>";
  $('Тег в который вы хотите вставить код').append(newLink);
}
```

Comment: вариант рабочий, но не оптимален тем, что ссылки добавляются по одной, а любая модификация DOM – операция «дорогая» – считается относительно долго. Гораздо лучше собрать в одной переменной весь HTML, и одним разом вставить в нужном месте.

Comment: @Sergiks, может тогда покажите как лучше сделать? спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант с использованием функций для работы с массивами:

- [Array.prototype.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) - заполняет массив указанным значением
- [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) - сворачивает массив в один объект

и следующими функциями jQuery:

- [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#returning-empty-set) - создание jQuery объекта с пустой коллекцией элементов
- [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/) - добавление элемента к набору
- [.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) - добавляет атрибут всем элементам в наборе, значение определяется в функции переданной вторым параметром
- [.text](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) - добавляет текст всем элементам в наборе, значение определяется в переданной функции
- [.append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) - добавляет параметр внутрь текущей выборки

```js
var N = 7;

function createLinks(n) {
  var links = [];
  links.length = n;
  return links.fill('<a>')
    .reduce((acc, cur) => acc.add(cur), $())
    .attr('href', function(i) {
      return '/page' + (i + 1)
    })
    .text(function(i) {
      return 'link ' + (i + 1)
    })
}

$('#out').append(createLinks(N)); // вставить готовый HTML в нужном месте
```

```css
a {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
```